# Recovering texts from iCloud

Tags: icloud

I lost my iPhone 4 and really need my text messages.  I always backed up everything to iCloud.  I don't have a new phone, but I do have a computer.

How can I go to iCloud and recover my texts?

Comment: Can you access iCloud from your computer ?

Comment: iCloud backups are not accessible from a computer. You would need to restore the backup onto a device to be able to access the messages.

Answer (score 1):

If your computer is a new enough Mac, if it has Messages.app installed, that should contain all your iMessages.

If you have a PC, I believe there are some programs that can extract your messages from your iPhone backups.

Comment: The first part is only true if iMessage was activated on the Mac prior to whatever messages are being searched for were sent.